# Taking the last element of the vectors from a list and create a new vector out of it

Tags: r, list

I want to create a data frame from the last elements of a list. I have describing two cases here, one easy and one a bit complecated.

**Easy case**

Let's assume a list or two vectors, `v`

```
v <- list("22" = c(2, 3, 5), "23" = c("aa", "bb")) 
> str(v)
List of 2
 $ 22: num [1:3] 2 3 5
 $ 23: chr [1:2] "aa" "bb"
```

I want to have a data frame where in the first column I will have the element names (here 22 and 23) and in the second column I will have the last element of that vector.

I can write the following codes to generate what I want,

```
last_elems1 <- lapply(v, tail, n = 1L)
last_elems1 <- data.frame(last_elems1) 
tidyr::gather(last_elems1)

> tidyr::gather(last_elems1)
  key value
1 X22     5
2 X23    bb
```

I have the following questions here,

1. How can I avoid the "X"s in the "key" column, e.i, I want only number 22, not X22.
2. Should I worry about the error message?

   Warning message:
   attributes are not identical across measure variables;
   they will be dropped

**Slightly complecated example**

Here I have list of two (or more) data frames with two vectors inside. The list can be generated as follows,

```
w <- list("22" = data.frame(a = c(2, 3, 5), 
                            b = c(5, 6, 8)), 
          "23" = data.frame(a = c(9, 10), 
                            b = c(11, 12))
          )
> str(w)
List of 2
 $ 22:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ a: num [1:3] 2 3 5
  ..$ b: num [1:3] 5 6 8
 $ 23:'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ a: num [1:2] 9 10
  ..$ b: num [1:2] 11 12
```

I want to have to last element of the variable b from each data frame inside the list. I am using the same codes described above, and that gives me the following,

```
last_elems2 <- lapply(w, tail, n = 1L)
last_elems2 <- data.frame(last_elems2)
tidyr::gather(last_elems2)

> tidyr::gather(last_elems2)
    key value
1 X22.a     5
2 X22.b     8
3 X23.a    10
4 X23.b    12
```

Here are my questions,

3. How to have the value in column `key` like `22` instead of `X22.b`.
4. I want only the row `2` and row `4`. That means, the output should be,

> ```
> tidyr::gather(last_elems2)
>    key value
> 1   22     8
> 2   23    12
> ```

Any idea how to fine tune what I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option

```
stack(lapply(w, function(x) {
  x[dim(x)[1], "b"] # return last element of column "b"
}))
#  values ind
#1      8  22
#2     12  23
```

When we use `dim`, we assume that `w` does not contain vectors - as a vector does not have a dimensions attribute. You would need to change that part to `x[length(x)]` then.

**data**

```
w <- list("22" = data.frame(a = c(2, 3, 5), 
                            b = c(5, 6, 8)), 
          "23" = data.frame(a = c(9, 10), 
                            b = c(11, 12))
)
```